# How do I resize a logical volume to the size of the filesystem within it?

Tags: centos7, centos6, lvm, kickstart

Target system is CentOS 6.x but resizing operations will be done in %pre section of CentOS 7.6 kickstart.

I have already run `resize2fs -M /dev/mapper/centos-home` successfully. 
If I mount the volume, df says it's 100% full. This is good.

Now I need to reduce the size of the logical volume to match the size of the ext4 filesystem. I don't want to use rough estimates. I also don't need to conserve every possible extent. Within a >= 1GB range is fine. i.e. volume can be reduced to 1GB >= filesystem size.

The target volume *does* contain data I can't lose. I don't have shell (or any other) access to the system. The system has no CentOS repos available so I cannot upgrade it. I don't even have remote hands I can talk to. I'm using a different computer to build and test my install ISO on.

My %pre syntax/script needs to safely reduce /dev/mapper/centos-home so I can create a new root volume for CentOS 7.6 install. Yes, this entire proposition is nuts.

Comment: `usedGB=$(df -h $homevol |  tail -1 | awk '{print $2}' | awk '{printf("%d\n",$1 + 1)}') ; echo $usedGB`
    prints '5'   
How do I use pass my variable $usedGB to lvreduce ?

Comment: `lvreduce -L -$usedGB\G /dev/mapper/centos-home`  
    WARNING: Reducing active logical volume to 15.00 GiB.
. . . but echo $usedGB reports only 5GB . . .

Comment: OK. I needed `$usedGB\G` not `-$usedGB\G`
Had to remove the hyphen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in one step.

```
/sbin/lvresize --resizefs --size -8g  /dev/mapper/centos-home
```

Where 8g is the size of the root volume you want to install.

Constant size may be acceptable because the size of your new install is predictable.

Comment: `/sbin/lvresize --resizefs --size -$usedGB\g  /dev/mapper/centos-root`  
This is the cleanest way.

Comment: If you have a script to calculate the maximum reduction, answer your own question with it. I find the constant reduction safer because if it cannot reduce by enough it aborts.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "constant reduction."

Comment: By constant reduction I mean hard coded reducing by 8g to simplify things. Consistent sizing of the volume, and if it fails there won't be enough space for the new volume.  Your script to detect how much to reduce is a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a script per se.

```
rootvol=/dev/mapper/vg_stt-lv_root
mkdir /tmp/rootlv
mount -t ext4 -o ro $rootvol /tmp/rootlv
usedROOT=$(df -h $rootvol |  tail -1 | awk '{print $2}' | awk '{printf("%d\n",$1 + 1)}')
umount /tmp/rootvol
/sbin/lvresize --resizefs --size $usedROOT\g  $rootvol
```